# How to remove child element without losing the content using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the `<p>` tag inside the `<h3>` without losing the content.

```
<h3 class="blog-heading">
    <p>This is content</p>
</h3>
```

I tried with `unwrap()`, `remove()` and `empty()` function but these functions are removing my data as well.

```
$('.blog-heading').find('p').remove();
```

Can any one guide me is this possible in jquery and how can i fix this. I will appreciate. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to unwrap `p` content:

```
$('.blog-heading p').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: Its working Thanks. It will be better if you explain how your code is working, that i could understand. Thank You

Comment: `contents()` will return textNode you want to unwrap. I'm not sure how to better explain it :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. Now i understood :)

Comment: This could be more readable: `$('.blog-heading p').replaceWith(function(){
   return $(this).text();
});`

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$('.blog-heading').text($('.blog-heading').find('p').text())
```